# Will there be any difference in solution for a weighted and unweighted graph? I mean is there any relation between weight and solution?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, mathematics, qaoa

I was working on max-cut problem. To do I have been given a graph of unweighted version, and I have to convert it into weighted version. I did it using qiskit. Now I was playing around the code, hence I have been assigning some arbitrary weight value to the edges. Then I found some confusing results. The more I am changing, the more I am unable to decode what is going on?

Lets elaborate, imagine this is my unweighted version graph (it is taken from qiskit textbook), in this graph weight is 1. so whenever I am changing the value of weight from 1 to 3,4,5 etc. I am not getting the desired solution {11011} or {00100}.

[image]

Comment: So you mean instead of having $H = \dfrac{1}{2}(1 - Z_iZ_j)$ you now have $H = \dfrac{w_{ij} }{2}(1 - Z_iZ_j)$?

Comment: yes. I have the weighted one. The problem I am facing on the approximate cost function is not matching.

Comment: Hello, could you maybe put the code you use to create the weighted graph and the results you think are weird with it please? I'll admit my first thought on this is that it is normal the solution might experience changes if you change the weight of some edges, because the function you need to maximise changes as well, so the solution is quite likely to evolve from the unweighted version.

Comment: yes, solution will evolve according to the weight of the edges. and its evolving as like as I am expecting. Let me pin down the discussion, after weighted edges I am expecting 12 but after doing simulation the approximate solution I am getting is 8. My question is, is it good enough solution? or should I reach more closer to 12?